# Is there anyway to play RTMPS video in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on task which will pull the video streaming from rtmps protocol, and I find no any solution to pull the video from that. and I always get a return message is 'protocol not found'

I'm try alot of flutter video player like better*player, vlc...* and still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no Flutter package, however, there are some implementations for Android and iOS. The Android version is working fine but the iOS version is under development. probably you can use method channel to utilize them for flutter:

[RootEncoder Android](https://github.com/pedroSG94/RootEncoder)

[RootEncoder iOS](https://github.com/pedroSG94/RootEncoder-iOS)